# Why don't I see UIPageControl?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I'm following these instructions per the ios docs on UIPageViewController and UIPageControl:

```
A page indicator will be visible if both methods are implemented, transition style is 'UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll', and navigation orientation is 'UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal'. Both methods are called in response to a 'setViewControllers:...' call, but the presentation index is updated automatically in the case of gesture-driven navigation.

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
```

So I have implemented them as follows, inside a UIViewController wrapper class:

Here is the initialization:

```
@interface PageViewWrapperViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic)  UIPageViewController *pageController;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger index;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *screenNumber;
@property UIPageControl *childPageControl;
@end

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        self.index = 0;
        self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
        self.pageController.dataSource = self;
        self.pageController.delegate = self;
        [self.pageController.view setFrame:[[self view] bounds]] ;
       UIViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];
        [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

        [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
        [[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
        //[self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController: self];

        self.childPageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
       // self.childPageControl = [self getPageControlForPageViewController:self.pageController];
        self.childPageControl.alpha = .5;
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.childPageControl];


    }
```

Here are the required methods for the UIPageControl:

```
  - (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
    {
        return 5;
    }

    -(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
    {
        return self.index;
    }
```

And here is where I give the PageController the individual view controllers:

```
- (UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{

    if(index==0)
    {
        //JudgeViewController *next1 = [[JudgeViewController alloc] init];
        JudgeTutorViewController *next1 = [[JudgeTutorViewController alloc] init];
        next1.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        return next1;

    }
    else if(index==1)
    {
        FollowTableViewController *next1 = [[FollowTableViewController alloc] init];
        next1.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        next1.typeDisplay = 1;
        return next1;

    }
    else if (index==2)
    {
        StatTutorViewController *next1 = [[StatTutorViewController
                                       alloc] init];
        next1.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        next1.user = [[UserObject userUnique] copyUser].name;
        return next1;
    }
    else if (index==3)
    {
        MenuTutorViewController *next1 = [[MenuTutorViewController
                                       alloc] init];
        next1.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        return next1;
    }
    else if(index ==4)
    {
        BuzzTutorViewController *next1 = [[BuzzTutorViewController alloc] init];
        next1.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        return next1;
    }
    self.index = index;
    return nil;
}
```

The UIPageViewController itself is working fine, but I don't see the UIPageControl. What is missing from my code?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, neither of these answers is what the problem is. In fact, I didn't change my code but once I flushed my build settings a few times that did the trick. Thank you all!

Comment: I pressed Control + Shift + K a bunch and just as I gave up they showed up. Not sure why this worked.  Probably did it 6 times while I was looking for an alternative course of action.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.childPageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
// self.childPageControl = [self getPageControlForPageViewController:self.pageController];
self.childPageControl.alpha = .5;
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.childPageControl];
```

At no point are you adding the page control as a subview. The view debugger in Xcode is a great way to spot missing UI elements like this.